# How to parse a JSON array

Tags: javascript, parsing, jsonp

new here and hit a roadblock, been searching but can't find the answer with my skill set. Task is pretty simple, I want to parse this http://data.sparkfun.com/output/AJ2p4r8Owvt1MyV8q9MV.json which is from a weather station. I have used the W3C tutorial but just can't seem to parse this file, but http://json.parser.online.fr has no problem. All the looping parse examples just give me alert after alert.

All I want is the ability to select temp[0] (out of god knows how many) for example via javascript and have it display on a website. I'm really lost, tried searching and if I've missed the goldmine then my bad. Thanks!

Example code

```
var text = '[{"humidity":"42.8000","stationtime":"2014-07-06 19:43:52","temp":"23.3000","timestamp":"2014-07-06T09:44:07.918Z"},{"humidity":"‌​43.0000","stationtime":"2014-07-06 19:42:57","temp":"23.2000","timestamp":"2014-07-06T09:42:22.003Z"},{"humidity":"‌​43.2000","stationtime":"2014-07-06 19:42:36","temp":"23.3000","timestamp":"2014-07-06T09:42:51.737Z"}]';  
var obj = JSON.parse(text); 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.temp[0];
```

Comment: Example of what I'm trying to do

`<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = '[{"humidity":"42.8000","stationtime":"2014-07-06 19:43:52","temp":"23.3000","timestamp":"2014-07-06T09:44:07.918Z"},{"humidity":"43.0000","stationtime":"2014-07-06 19:42:57","temp":"23.2000","timestamp":"2014-07-06T09:42:22.003Z"},{"humidity":"43.2000","stationtime":"2014-07-06 19:42:36","temp":"23.3000","timestamp":"2014-07-06T09:42:51.737Z"}]';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.temp[0];
</script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: do NOT post code in comments. Add it to the question

Comment: remove single quote from `var text = '[{"humidity":"4 ..'`

Comment: You should edit your question to say 'how to parse json', and not 'jsonp' as these are two different things (jsonp is a method of bypassing cross-origin restrictions).

Comment: But he needs JSONP to get at the JSON

Comment: But his issue is with parsing the json, not performing the JSONP request. The answer he is looking for was posted by @Rajesh (he missed the fact the JSON is an array, not an object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery makes working with JSONP much easier heres an example (http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/9mBsr/)

```
$.getJSON('http://data.sparkfun.com/output/AJ2p4r8Owvt1MyV8q9MV.json?callback=?', function (data) {
    data.forEach(function (item) {
        $('body').append(JSON.stringify(item)); 
    });
})
```

**update again**

heres another example using your code (http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/9mBsr/2/)

```
var text = '[{"humidity":"42.8000","stationtime":"2014-07-06 19:43:52","temp":"23.3000","timestamp":"2014-07-06T09:44:07.918Z"},{"humidity":"‌43.0000","stationtime":"2014-07-06 19:42:57","temp":"23.2000","timestamp":"2014-07-06T09:42:22.003Z"},{"humidity":"‌43.2000","stationtime":"2014-07-06 19:42:36","temp":"23.3000","timestamp":"2014-07-06T09:42:51.737Z"}]';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj[0].temp;
```

Comment: Thanks Chad! So very close to what I'm after, what would I have to change in order to select just one of the temps for example? Using some kind of obj.temp[1] I'm assuiming?

Comment: your problem is that there is no obj.temp, its just obj[1], try pasting your JSON into the console wrapped in ( ). It makes it much easier to see the contents of the JSON object. (http://img42.com/sQVtD+ - chrome console)

Comment: Thanks Chad, that's a real bummer. So there is no easy way using the original $.getJSON method to extract the temperature from the first object? Must be close.

Comment: Brilliant! One last thing is how can I use http://data.sparkfun.com/output/AJ2p4r8Owvt1MyV8q9MV.json?callback=? with that second example, the var text one? As I need the page to grab the values and update automatically. Really appreciate your help, seriously got me out of a bind.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to parse the incoming string as below:

```
temp_arr = JSON.parse(json_string);
```

Just loop over the temp_arr array, and in each iteration of loop you'll have one object (tobj). For example, like this:

```
{"humidity":"40.9000","stationtime":"2014-07-06 21:21:03","temp":"22.6000","timestamp":"2014-07-06T11:20:27.231Z"}
```

All you have to do is, access it like tobj.temp and use it to display on page.

I have written a jquery implementation at: **http://jsfiddle.net/DNH5n/2/**

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thanks for the reply! Any chance you could help me with the code, putting a working example together? My knowledge is limited with Java.

Comment: this is not Java, but javascript. Both are VERY DIFFERENT.

Comment: I took a look at the jsfiddle and definitely useful for me, I'm working on charts now and think this will help a lot. Thanks!